# Configure @Autowired from application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have some beans that are conditional

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperties("${condition}")
class Foo {
 ...
}
```

We want to be able to autowire those bean based on the same condition, is there a way to do something like:

```
@Autowired(required="${condition}")
private Foo foo;
```

Is there a way to obtains such result using properties from application.yml ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Foo as bean with `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "condition", havingValue = "true")` like below

```
@Configuration
public class BasicConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "condition", havingValue = "true")
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Inject this **foo** bean as

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Foo foo;
```

`@Autowired(required = false)` is for make this field as optional.

Whenever condition satisfied, here foo will have value otherwise it will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SPEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#expressions).
For example: `@Autowired(required="#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }")`

Comment: The problem is that ``required`` expect a boolean so this doesn't pass the compilation